# Multiple Atmega328p wired communication

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, communication, wire-library, prototype

I am using multiple ATMEGA328Ps  (4 ATMEGA328P) (OR Arduino Unos). The distance between two farthest ATMEGAs is 14 meters (One is Master Device and Other is Node), and other 3 are connected to each other at a distance of 3 meters from the Master Device.
I have a case where i cannot use Wireless communication hence i will have to go Wired. I am also looking to achieve the Mesh topology if possible.

There are many examples on the internet regarding this case but still i am not be able to choose/compare which would be more reliable.

Please suggest me the best solution to work on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Mesh is kind of silly, if it's wired. You haven't told us what you want to communicate. That is; how much data, at what data-rate? Master to slave only, or bi-directional?

Comment: a token-ring-like topology will be easier to manage; just give each device a unique ID and each message a list of IDs which are intended recipients. Once a node receives the message, it removes its ID and forwards the message, if there are any IDs left to consume... Somewhat like I2C.

Comment: How about 1-Wire? Here is an example of a 1-Wire Master and Slave that allows distributed digitalRead/Write/pinMode/etc. Master https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-OWI/blob/master/examples/Arduino/Arduino.ino, and Slave, https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-OWI/blob/master/examples/Slave/Arduino/Arduino.ino.

Comment: @Gerben : Thanks for the quick reply. My Goal is to achieve bi-directional , one master and multiple slaves ( request , response , ack , broadcasting ), long distance upto 20 meters , max to max 20 bytes of data to be sent.

Comment: @dandavis : thanks i will think about this. nice idea.

Comment: @MikaelPatel : 1-wire not recommended over long distance.